# AudioKit 5 and Xcode 12 beta 6 Build Errors

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I'm trying to build a project using AudioKit 5 (master branch) XCFrameworks in XCode 12 beta 6 for iOS 14 and I'm getting 1 warning and 2 errors:

Warning:

> Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftAVFoundation'

Error 1:

> Undefined symbol:
> _swiftoverride_class_getSuperclass(swift::TargetMetadataswift::InProcess
> const*)

Error 2:

> Undefined symbol:
> swift::swift51override_conformsToSwiftProtocol(swift::TargetMetadataswift::InProcess
> const*, swift::TargetProtocolDescriptorswift::InProcess const*,
> llvm::StringRef,
> swift::TargetProtocolConformanceDescriptorswift::InProcess const*
> (*)(swift::TargetMetadataswift::InProcess const*,
> swift::TargetProtocolDescriptorswift::InProcess const*,
> llvm::StringRef))

Any ideas why this might be happening?
**Note:** The exact same project works fine in XCode 11 when building for iOS 13.7.

Comment: Are you sure `AudioKit` even supports Xcode 12? Btw this sort of question would better be raised as an [issue on AudioKit's GitHub page](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/issues).

Comment: Mmm, that's a good question. I was on the impression that AudioKit 5 was the branch supporting XCode 12 and iOS 14... but perhaps I was wrong. I'll ask in the GitHub page as you suggested.

Comment: Just checked on the GitHub page but it seems that's not the right place to raise this issue, this is the message I get when opening a new issue:

If your issue is implementing AudioKit in your own code, post your problem to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=AudioKit) with the #AudioKit hashtag.
GitHub Issues should only be used for confirmed problems with AudioKit and
well-defined feature requests.

Comment: Using AudioKit with a new version of Xcode is clearly an issue with AudioKit itself and not with your custom code - hence it should be raised on their GitHub page. This is something that AudioKit itself needs to support - hence only the maintainers of the framework can achieve that.

Comment: That's clear, I'll give it a shot then, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what info the error is giving, it sounds like it Xcode is having trouble finding the Swift 5.1 methods which makes sense. Xcode beta will be using the latest version of Swift which I believe is 5.3

You should try what @megastep says. I just built the `v5-develop` branch and ran the `AKMIDITrackView` example on my iPhone with the latest iOS 14.0 beta 8 and Xcode 12 beta 6.

You can check out the example here if you want to try building a demo AudioKit project which is helpful to do sometimes: https://github.com/AudioKit/MIDITrackView

And that's right! I just discovered the Swift packages which is a very nice feature. I believe if you just select the `Code` button on an example project and select `Open with Xcode` everything will be taken care of for you.

In my tutorial, I wasn't using Xcode beta which is why I chose to use the `v5-master` branch. I should have made that more clear. I'll make sure to do that next time.

Comment: In my case it helped to rebuild binary libraries with higher iOS target - OpenCV had minimum iOS version 8, which is not supported by XCode 12 and iOS 14. XCode failed to build the project with rather cryptic error about missing `_swiftoverride_class_getSuperclass` and `swift51override_conformsToSwiftProtocol` during linking.

Comment: @ph4r05 That seems like something which could cause that issue. The minimum target iOS version might factor into which compiler Xcode chooses to use. I just realized that Xcode 12 also doesn't include the Swift 5.1 compiler, so that explains a lot. You can read which compilers Xcode 12 supports here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/GuidedTour/Compatibility.html.

Answer (score 2):

AudioKit 5 definitely *does* support Xcode 12 - however maybe you are using the wrong branch. You should really be checking out the `v5-develop` branch instead of master for the latest changes.

In addition, this branch currently works with the Swift Package Manager which should alleviate the need to compile the frameworks by yourself.

This branch is very much in flux though with lots of changes to the API so you will probably have to adapt your code.

Comment: Is there a documentation to those changes? I can't seem to find it. I need to rewrite frequency tracking in my app, since AudioKit.output does not work now.

Comment: Yeah I don't think there's much documentation yet though I think they're working on some new examples for this.